# How to check for NULL or a single object in a list returned by JSON deserialization using Newtonsoft JSON.NET in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, null, json.net

I am deserializing a JSON result as follows:

```
responsebody = WebClient.DownloadString(URI);
Console.WriteLine(responsebody);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responsebody))
{
    throw new Exception("The request returned empty Position Object.");
}
if (responsebody.Length > 0)
{
    //dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responsebody);
    //if (dynObj.positions == null)
    //{
    //    throw new Exception("The request returned empty Position Object.");
    //}

    RootPositions PosList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootPositions>(responsebody);

    if (PosList.positions.position.Count() > 1)
        foreach (var p in PosList.positions.position)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id : {0}", p.id);
            Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0}", p.symbol);
            Console.WriteLine("Quantity : {0}", p.quantity);
            Console.WriteLine("Average Price : {0}", p.cost_basis);
        }
}
return responsebody;
```

The class for the above deserialization is as follows:

```
//******** JSON Object to PositionData Class
    public class RootPositions
    {
        public PositionList positions { get; set; }
    }

    public class PositionList
    {
        //[JsonConverter(typeof(GenericListCreationJsonConverter<Position>))]
        public List<Position> position { get; set; }
    }

    public class Position
    {
        public float cost_basis { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public decimal quantity { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
    }
```

My code doesnt work the way I am handling if I get a NULL JSON result as below.

JSON returned: `"{\"positions\":\"null\"}"` or {"positions":"null"}

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: {"Error converting value \"null\" to type 'ApiPost.PositionList'. Path 'positions', line 1, position 19."}
System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to ApiAddIn.PositionList.
```

How can I check for NULL and also how can I check if the JSON is giving back a Position List or only 1 position.
Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `"{\"positions\":\"null\"}"` and not `"{\"positions\": null}"` (no quotes around null) ?

Comment: I'm sorry for the Output format. This is what I intended: `{"positions":"null"}`

Comment: That's seems like a problem: with quotes around null, it means then `position` property is a string. If `null` was not quoted, you deserialization code would be correct. Do you generate/control that JSON response?

Comment: As mentioned in the above question I have a class which JSON is deserialized into. I just need to check the output and if it is NULL I shall implement the logic. But how do I check if the list object returned NULL?

Comment: the problem is that `{"positions":"null"}` does not represent a `RootPositions` object with its `positions` property set to null, but an object which has a `positions` property of type string with a value of "null". It's not the same thing.

Comment: What if the entire list is returned as null?

Comment: that should be `{"positions": null}`.